# Is it possible to write a regex to find multiple spaces that are NOT within pairs of speech or quotation marks?

Tags: regex, typescript

I need a (TypeScript) regex pattern that will match on 2 or more consecutive spaces that are not within speech or quotation marks.

Say I have this string:

```
"John    Smith" and Sarah Brown    are    having 'a     ' nice(" .    ")   day tod'   'ay.
```

I want to match on (and then remove) all of the 2+ white space substrings that are not within a pair of "" or ''. Basically, anything inside a pair of speech or quotation marks should be ignored. Is anyone able to provide me with a snippet that will do that?

Alternatively, is anyone able to recommend a suitable lexing or parsing npm library that would be able to do this? I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lexing), but I'm not sure if Ill be able to use it to perform this task.

Comment: Maybe you can use [The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick), something like [`"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|(  +)`](https://regex101.com/r/0IVh2r/1) and check for being [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) or not on programside (use some function with [`replace`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typescript-string-replace-method/)).

Comment: See [this JS demo](https://tio.run/##HY3NCsIwEITvfYohlzT@VL2JpQoevXoUxaUNbaVJJI0VUZ@9bpzDDsMw@91ooL707T3Mh/U4djqgDx4FruLgGgvW0bShESBb4UieGuy9e/4b8jpaQ0Nra0iKARK2LXUqkMUkFJ@KXgiukrGlV3bNkySCvO4ZxLjM63tHPFqI00WcJ@IjTxd5nshPCkzVop4hNcuZWSkUW7wT8DQ8vIVZYcdAiQ3MMk@@ij@Xzvau01nn6pQJKh/HHw) (not sure about typescript and if that's what you want to do).

Comment: Can your double-quoted sections contain escaped double-quotes?

Comment: @jhnc to my knowledge, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tsplay.dev/wX161N

```
const text = `"John    Smith" and Sarah Brown    are    having 'a     ' nice(" .    ")   day tod'   'ay.`

/*
from:
  /
    (               select as $1
      '[^']*'       text in ' quotes
      |             or
      "[^"]*"       text in " quotes
    )               end $1
    |
    ( )             select space as $2
    [ ]+            spaces 
  /g
to:
  $1                keep $1 text in quotes
  $2                keep $2 first space
*/

const result = text.replaceAll(/('[^']*'|"[^"]*")|( )[ ]+/g, '$1$2')
console.log(result)
// "John    Smith" and Sarah Brown are having 'a     ' nice(" .    ") day tod'   'ay.
// "John    Smith" and Sarah Brown ^^^are ^^^having 'a     ' nice(" .    ") ^^day tod'   'ay.
```

Comment: Even better idea, very nice.

Comment: Thanks, this answer seems to work. Thanks also for your contributions @bobblebubble